# Deleting / Updating / Inserting data in correct order MSSQL -> MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, powershell

My issue currently is as follows:

I have Table `A`, that copies items to a transfer table based on whether an Update, Insert or Delete transaction has occurred on Table `A` i.e.

Table `A` -> new insert

Trigger activates and inserts row into Transfer table with 2 other columns - `DateQueried` and `QueryType` (Where `DateQueried` is the date the trigger fired and `QueryType` is 'Delete', 'Insert' or 'Update' depending on the trigger type)

However, now I need to transfer this data to a web server by a linked table (all this is fine and doing as it should). Currently I have a PowerShell script to do this. The script does the following:

- Select all values from my transfer table, orders by `datequeried`
- Run a foreach loop that runs a stored procedure to either insert / update / delete that value to the web server, depending on the value of `QueryType`.

This method is extremely slow, the script runs on a 30 minute timer and we can have a situation where we receive over 100,000 rows within that 30 minute time frame, which means 100,000 connections to the DB via the PowerShell script (especially when there's 15 tables that need to run through this process).

Is there a better way to get these values out by running an inner join? Previously I would just run the entire table at once through a stored procedure that would delete all values from the second server with a `QueryType` of delete, then run inserts then updates. However, this had some issues if a person was to create a new job, then delete the job, then recreate the job, then update the job, then delete the job again. My stored procedure would process all deletes, THEN all inserts, THEN all updates, so even though the row was deleted it would go and insert it back again.

I then rejigged it yet again and instead transferred primary keys across only and whenever I ran the stored procedure it would process deletes based on primary keys, then for inserts and updates it would first join to the original table on the primary keys (which if it was previously deleted would return no results and therefore not insert). But I ran into a problem where the query was chewing up way too much resources for the process and bombing out the server at times (it had to attempt to join > 100,000 results to a table that has over 10 million rows). Also there was another issue where it would insert a row with only null values for each column where the join wouldn't work. Then when it happened again there would be a primary key error and the stored procedure would stop.

Is there another option I am overlooking that would make the process here a great deal faster or am I just stuck with the limitations on the server and maybe have to suggest that the company only processes uploads at the end of every day rather than the 30 minute schedule they would like?

Comment: This appears to be a question about replication

Answer (score 2):

Stick with bulk Delete/Insert/update order.

But:

- Only insert rows where a later delete is not there (all
  changes are lost anyway)
- Only process updates where a later insert OR delete rows aren't there (all
  changes would be overwritten)

Comment: Thanks Nigel, So for this:
On INSERT
would i just join it to itself (transfer table to transfer table) WHERE a.DateQueried < b.DateQueried AND QueryType != 'Delete'

Then for UPDATE
same thing except where QueryType != 'Insert' or 'Delete'

Therefore making the join pull no results for a match?

Comment: If you do this as WHERE NOT EXISTS, as this will check for not later row of whatever type you want to exclude.